# Why Long.parseLong(String s) won't consider a trailing "L" as valid?

Tags: java, long-integer

```
Long myLong = Long.parseLong("1L") // Throws NumberFormatException
```

My best guess is that an additional check like that would cause an overhead which would only come into play ~1% (or less) of the time anyone calls `parseLong` with a trailing "L" character.

But is there perhaps a different reason behind this "omission"?

Comment: You put the L there to identify longs in code, it has essentially no meaning. It's the same as any other letter or character. Just remove it.

Comment: But wouldn't it be useful for cases when code needs to analyze code?

Comment: You are already explicity telling it that you are dealing with a `long`. The additional `L` is required for number liters, because if it is missing the number implicity represents an `int`(or `double` for floating point numbers) and not a `long`.

Comment: You usually don't analyze java with java.

Comment: @Bálint What are you basing that on? There are plenty of Java code (such as maven plugins) that are written in Java and analyze Java source code.

Comment: @Kayaman it's very rare and for only that, it is really a waste to implement

Comment: @Bálint You should tell the developers of [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) that it's rare (it's not).

Answer (score 4):

It is defined so in the method java.lang.Long.parseLong(String):

> The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that
>   the first character may be an ASCII minus sign ...

Answer (score 1):

The trailing `L` (or `l`) is only relevant to the Java *compiler* to distinguish `int` literals from `long` literals. It's not a universal marker for long values, so accepting (and ignoring) it would be more of a weird side effect, not to mention a source for bugs.

Comment: But Double.parseDouble and Float.parseFloat accept suffixes f and d respectively. So, this is kind of weird.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about the use case of `Long.parseLong("1L");` is you got long value in the form of `String` with `l` at the end.

Now how can you get this value in real life applications, consider GUI or console application, conversion of number `String` to actual type will not have suffix `l` or `d`. From user input to database value suffix `l` is not acceptable for number input. You will never get `String` value as `1L` from the business logic for the conversion to actual `Long` value.

Surprisingly, on the other hand `Double myDouble = Double.parseDouble("1d");` will work fine because `sun.misc.FloatingDecimal` managed to parse with suffix `d` in number because `double` value may contain other characters like `E` or `e` in it for exponential term.

Answer (score 1):

The `L` in `1L` indicates to the Java compiler that the value is a `long` **literal**. It only has meaning in the Java source code for disambiguation with `1` (an `int` literal).

When you use `Long.parseLong(String)` with the string `"1L"`, it is a runtime error, because `L` is not a valid numerical digit in base 10. There is also no need for disambiguation, as you have already explicitly declared you want a `Long` as the result.

Or more formally, the documentation of [`Long.parseLong(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-) specifies:

> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal long. The characters in the 
>   string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may
>   be an ASCII minus sign '`-`' (`\u002D`') to indicate a negative value
>   or an ASCII plus sign '`+`' ('`\u002B`') to indicate a positive value.
>   The resulting `long` value is returned, exactly as if the argument and
>   the radix `10` were given as arguments to the
>   [`parseLong(java.lang.String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-int-) method.
>
> Note that neither the character `L` ('`\u004C`') nor `l` ('`\u006C`')
>   is permitted to appear at the end of the string as a type indicator,
>   as would be permitted in Java programming language source code.

This last paragraph explicitly documents it is not allowed.