# Is it possible to convert the String "1L" to the corresponding Long value?

Tags: java, type-conversion, config

I am parsing a config file with the following instructions:

```java
public String getProperty(String key) throws IOException {
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  String path = "path/to/file/file.properties";
  InputStream stream = this.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
  prop.load(stream);
  return prop.getProperty(key);
```

The returned value, that is a `String`, is later converted into the expected type from the calling method. How can I convert the String `1L` into a `Long` type? 
I tried:

```java
Long.valueOf(this.getProperty(key));
```

but it raises `NumberFormatException`. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You might want to look into the `substring()` method.

Comment: There is no standard API for parsing [JLS 3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) integer constants into the corresponding value the way a Java compiler would if that's what you mean.

Comment: You are reading the entire properties file for getting a single property? I hope, you’re not calling this method once for each property you’re interested in…

Comment: @Holger. You know it!

Comment: Related: [Why Long.parseLong(String s) won't consider a trailing "L" as valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739676/why-long-parselongstring-s-wont-consider-a-trailing-l-as-valid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `Long.parseLong` nor `Long.valueOf` can directly parse `1L`.

A workaround: You can implement a simple `stripTrailingL` function to remove the trailing `L` and then parse it to Long.

```java
String str = "1234L";
Long yourLong = Long.parseLong(stripTrailingL(str));

public String stripTrailingL(String str) {
    return str.endsWith("L") ? str.substring(0, str.length() - 1) : str;
}
```

Comment: No need for a big dependency if all you want is a simple substring. Otherwise, the answer is okay. Also, OP might not be using maven as a build tool, there are others as well (and using none is also an option).

Comment: Adding a dependency for `substring()` makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just improved my answer.